# EJS include partials and declare variables for partials - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have an EJS file where I include a header:

`<% include ../partials/header %>`

In that header I have some tags (title, description) which have to change depending on the location.

I'm having some issues passing variables to the include.

Controller

```
var title = 'title',
    description = 'description bla bla';
//...
res.render('home', {title: title, description: description});
```

View (partials/header)

```
<meta name="title" content="<%= title %>">
<meta name="description" content="<%= description %>">
```

Now my problem, when I start the `nodejs` server the website renders correctly the variables, however I get errors saying that the variables `title` and `description` have not been defined.

I'm not sure if I'm doing this the correct way.

Comment: What do you mean by " however I have logs about the variables  title and description not being defined  " Please explain

Comment: The website renders correctly. However in the nodejs console I have errors saying that the variables have been not defined.

Comment: I have the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49616441/ejs-passing-dynamic-property-to-include-results-in-an-error